# How can I add Total records in the Json object with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I had implemented pagination on my fronted side thus it requires total records in the Json object with the data inside it for the specific page number, But i don't know how can i append total records to the Json object which i am returning from my sprinBoot main controller.

Currently i am getting Json object of

```
[
    {
        "name": "wrvee",
        "email_id": "as@gmail.com",
        "check_in": null,
        "check_out": null,
        "data": null
    },
    {
        "name": "sefse",
        "email_id": "vsd@gmail.com",
        "check_in": null,
        "check_out": null,
        "data": null
    }
]
```

But I am looking for :

```
[
   total_records:100
   data: {
        "name": "wrvee",
        "email_id": "as@gmail.com",
        "check_in": null,
        "check_out": null,
        "data": null
    },
    {
        "name": "sefse",
        "email_id": "vsd@gmail.com",
        "check_in": null,
        "check_out": null,
        "data": null
    }
]
```

My SpringBoot Code of main controller where i am getting the data from the service class using List and returning it in the method.

```
@GetMapping("/view")
    public List<TableModel> view(
            @RequestParam(value="page",defaultValue = "1",required = false) Integer page
            ) {
        
        return service.view(page);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what ianperfitt said and create a class like

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
class MyResponse {
   private List<Records> records;
   private int count;
}
```

or exactly as you asked as

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
class MyResponse {
   private List<Records> data;
   private int total_records;
}
```

and then in your controller

```
@GetMapping("/{pageOROffset}/{size}")
public MyResponse someMethodName(@PathVariable(name = "pageOrOffset") int page, @PathVariable(name = "size") int batchSize) {
  List<Records> records = dao.findAll(PageRequest.of(page, size));
  return new MyResponse(records, records.size());
}
```

or you could be lazy and pretend the class is class and skip it and just do

```
@GetMapping("/{pageOROffset}/{size}")
public Map<String, Object> someMethodName(@PathVariable(name = "pageOrOffset") int page, @PathVariable(name = "size") int batchSize) {
  List<Records> records = dao.findAll(PageRequest.of(page, size));
  return Map.of("data", records, "total_record_count", records.size());
}
```

Note: Map.of() is a feature of Java 11+ and if you're not up to that version you could just do

```
@GetMapping("/{pageOROffset}/{size}")
public Map<String, Object> someMethodName(@PathVariable(name = "pageOrOffset") int page, @PathVariable(name = "size") int batchSize) {
  List<Records> records = dao.findAll(PageRequest.of(page, size));
  HashMap<String, Object> res = new HashMap<>();
  res.put("data", records);
  res.put("total_record_count", records.size();
  return res;
}
```

Map<String, Object> is the closest thing we have to a javascript object in terms of just being able to create a loosely defined pojo on the fly.

Note: @AllArgsConstructor, @NoArgsConstructor, @Data are all annotations provided by lombok, which saves you a lot of boiler plate code

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a Class object that has two members from your Controller:

1. an int called "total_records"
2. a List of TableModel objects called "data"

The class could be called TableModelDTO where DTO stands for data transfer object.

The JSON would look slightly different than the JSON you provided in the second image

```
{ "total_records" : 100,
  "data" : [{
    "name": "wrvee",
    "email_id": "as@gmail.com",
    "check_in": null,
    "check_out": null,
    "data": null
},
{
    "name": "sefse",
    "email_id": "vsd@gmail.com",
    "check_in": null,
    "check_out": null,
    "data": null
 }]
}
```